# JavaScript and Google Chrome extension project

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am currently in the process of creating a script for a Google chrome extension that allows me to automate the process of adding items and checking out on a website that I use often. I have seen posts in the past in regards to doing this for Nike.com, however I am trying to do this with SupremeNewYork.com and the existing script I have works for Nike.com, but I cannot figure out how to update it so that it will work for SupremeNewYork.com. Here is what I have so far, and I was wondering if someone could please help me with this!

```
var size_i_want = "Medium";

function fRun()
    {
    // Select size option.
    var sizesList=document.getElementsByName("skuAndSize")[0];
    for(var i=0; i<sizesList.length; i++)
    {
        if(sizesList.options[i].text.trim() == size_i_want)
        {
            sizesList.selectedIndex = i;
        }
    }

    var aButtons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
    for(var i = 0; i < aButtons.length; ++i)
    {
        if(aButtons[i].className.indexOf("add-to-cart") > -1)
        {
            aButtons[i].click();
        }
    }
}

function fTick()
{
    if(document.getElementsByName("skuAndSize")[0] != undefined)
    {
        setTimeout("fRun()", 600);
         //fRun();
    }else{
        setTimeout("fTick()", 300);
    }
}
setTimeout("fTick()", 300);
```

Comment: @SLaks whenever I add this as a chrome extension and enable it nothing happens. It doesnt add anything to my cart, and Im unsure as to why.

Comment: Your question (rather: request) is basically "Please convert this existing Chrome extension to work with a different website". This is not what Stackoverflow is about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you made two mistakes.

First, you seems unaware that the HTML structure or identifier names of SupremeNewYork.com differ from that of Nike.com. Because your script currently relies on the HTML structure or identifier names *of Nike.com*, you need to investigate that *of SupremeNewYork.com* by viewing source code of the pages and rewrite your script for SupremeNewYork.com.

Second, it is a simple mistake.
`i<sizesList.length` should be `i<sizesList.options.length`.

I hope that the following script will solve your problem.

```
var size_i_want = "Medium";

function fRun()
    {
    // Select size option.
    var sizesList=document.getElementsByName("size")[0];
    for(var i=0; i<sizesList.options.length; i++)
    {
        if(sizesList.options[i].text.trim() == size_i_want)
        {
            sizesList.selectedIndex = i;
        }
    }

    var commitButton = document.getElementsByName("commit")[0];
    commitButton.click();
}

function fTick()
{
    if(document.getElementsByName("size")[0] != undefined)
    {
        setTimeout("fRun()", 600);
         //fRun();
    }else{
        setTimeout("fTick()", 300);
    }
}
setTimeout("fTick()", 300);
```

Comment: Thank you, I now see where I messed up, I appreciate all of your help!